# Displaying all the collapsible content in Accordion using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, accordion

Suppose I want to simulate a scenario, where a user wants to see all the collapsible content like the [Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) widget, one by one, with some wait, in between two clicks ( at most 2-3 seconds)

The user clicks on Section 1, then waits for 2 seconds and then clicks on Section 2, and so on.

I thought of implementing in this way

```
package com.rahul.misc;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class accordion {
public WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;

public static void main(String[] args) {
 accordion acc=new accordion();
 acc.checkFirefox();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void checkFirefox(){
driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

baseUrl="http://jqueryui.com/accordion/";
driver.get(baseUrl);


List<WebElement> allinks= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".ui-accordion-header"));
for(WebElement w:allinks){
    new Actions(driver).click().build().perform();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}
}

This code compiles correctly but it does nothing. I am skeptical about part where I have put all the elements in list. Is this the correct way to catch all the web elements for the widget. If no how do I do it.

Also is the action performed correct? Because in the scenario, user won't be doing in, he'll be just clicking on the collapsible header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your code isn't doing anything is because the elements are contained in an `iframe`.  `findElements()` does not throw an exception if no elements are found, thus your code runs to completion.

You can fix that part like so:

```
baseUrl="http://jqueryui.com/accordion/";
driver.get(baseUrl);
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".demo-frame")));
```

Once you're done in the `iframe`, you'll need to switch back out like so:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

I believe you'll encounter another issue on this line:

```
new Actions(driver).click().build().perform();
```

`click()` in an `Actions` context clicks where the mouse currently is.  As you haven't told the mouse where to point, it's clicking somewhere, but not on the element you wish.  You can fix this a couple of different ways.

I would recommend this:

```
w.click();
```

If you want to stay with the `Actions` chain, you can fix it like this:

```
new Actions(driver).click(w).build().perform();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It perfect. Forgot about the iframe thing.